# Verify $(H_1 \cap H_2)g=H_1g \cap H_2g$ where $H_1,H_2\leq G$ and $g\in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Verify $(H_1 \cap H_2)g=H_1g \cap H_2g$ where $H_1,H_2\leq G$ and $g\in G$.

Let $S_1,S_2\leq G,g\in G$
What i had done, $x\in (S_1 \cap S_2)g$. Then $x=sg,s\in S_1\cap S_2$. So clearly, $x\in S_1g$ and $x\in S_2g$ hence $x\in S_1g\cap S_2g$.

But for the reverse inclusion, I let $x\in S_1g\cap S_2g$. Then $x\in S_1g$ and $x\in S_2g$. Next, $x=s_1g=s_2g$ for some $s_1\in S_1,s_2\in S_2$. Then i stuck here. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a group, $s_1g = s_2g$ implies $s_1 = s_2$.